# Using 'd%' to delete a bracket pair and its contents is now broken

Tags: plugin-matchit

I've long been editing code in Vim 7.4 with `matchit` and `matchparen` plugins.  In my old setup it was easy to delete `{ some string }` by placing the cursor on the `{` and then use the <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> command.

I've now moved to a new computer system (and new job) with a fresh install of Vim 8.2 and I believe I've got the same plugins, but now when I use the <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> command, it keeps the closing `}`.

This change in behavior now makes editing my code much more cumbersome as I have to deal with the closing `}` (or [`)\]`, etc]) separately.

Could someone who understands the plugins or key mapping please tell me how to get back to the behavior where the terminating character is also deleted (or selected/yanked/etc).

Comment: there _is_ no vim 8.3... what version are you using exactly?

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Using Vim 8.2, without any plugin, I get the behaviour you like. Have you tried with `vim --clean`(which will launch a bare vim instance) to make sure your config is not causing this issue?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You can use the `:map %` command to check whether you have `%` mapped by a plug-in or not and what it's mapped to. (Better yet, `:verbose map %` will also include the name of the file where it was defined.) I can't reproduce the issue you're reporting, either with matchit or without it... Haven't tried matchparen. But please check which one you're using first.

Comment: Note that you can use `da{` to delete a block inside curly braces. And you can use that command anywhere inside the block, not only on top of the `{` itself. I'd be happy to turn these comments into an answer, but I wanted to be able to explain why you're seeing the behavior you're currently seeing...

Comment: you can use da} to delete everything between {} including the braces, and you can use di} to delete everything between {} not including the braces.

Comment: this might be a matchit bug. If you can reproduce this with a minimal example, please open an issue here: https://github.com/chrisbra/matchit/ I'd like to have this fixed

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to filbranden for expanding my Vim command library with the `:map %` and `da{` / `di{` commands - those will surely prove useful.

Using those commands, and some useful diff tools, I identified that I was using a badly obsolete version of matchit.  Deleting my bad plugin, and following the instructions in `:help matchit-install`, I was able to correct my installation, and return to the expected behavior of <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>

.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out and thanks for looping back with the solution!